# pandas.read_csv duplicate issue

Tags: python, pandas

**Solution:** removing the print statement shows the data once. But I do not understand the logic behind this?

This seems like a very straightforward issue but I am having a great deal of trouble finding a solution or anyone else that has replicated this issue.

I am simply trying to read some data from a csv using pandas. The csv is fairly large and I thought was the cause of the issue but I created a new test case csv by hand which is simply a 3x3 grid:

```
 A  b  c
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
```

This also caused the issue that I have not seen before. Essentially when I interact with the dataframe it is replicated twice.

```
import json #(for later use)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("Workbook1.csv")

print (data)
```

output:

```
   A  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
   A  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

print (type(data))
```

output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

It's not the case that I can drop the first few rows to delete one half either:

```
data.drop(data.index[0], axis =0, inplace = True)
print (data)
```

output:

```
   A  b  c
1  4  5  6
   A  b  c
1  4  5  6
```

It seems like the strangest problem that I have not seen before from using pandas and reading files multiple times with no such similar issue.

**Edit**
Further to this, when I remove the `'import json'` at the top, the script fails all together stating that `'module' object has no attribute 'read_csv'`

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np

  data = pd.read_csv('Workbook1.csv')
  data
```

Results in AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_csv'

Comment: remove the print() statement and try. just run data.

Comment: Thank you @AjayShah that has worked! Could you please explain to me what is going on here?

Comment: IMO, already you get an output by typing the name of the dataframe. Then, on top you have the print statement. That may duplicate. Can't zero in though. Please edit the question for the latter part with example of module object has no attribute 'read_csv'. Also, please upvote my first comment. ;)

Comment: If you put your comment as an answer as opposed to a comment I can? Fairly new to this sorry. It could be due to a reputation level

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the strange behaviour of my script is due to the fact that a compiled version of the script had been created with extension .pyc

I had read an answer to a similar problem that suggested changing the name of the script (my script was named json.py so thought this could cause issues). Upon changing the name of the script I now had test.py but with json.pyc in the same directory. When I run the script, somehow the compiled version was continuing to be referenced therefore I continued to see the same issues. Removing the .pyc extension file solved my issue.